# ReferenceError: message is not defined popping up randomly

Tags: discord.js

So i'm making a discord bot and trying to implement music with discord.js, node-opus, and ytdl-core. But randomly, while executing commands (mostly >>stop) I will get a ReferenceError which completely stop the command, while trying another time, without changes, the command will complete successfully. Any help?

[Bot Snippet](https://hastebin.com/icarezicaf.coffeescript)
| Below is the error that occurrs randomly while executing commands.

```
(node:11740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined
at StreamDispatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\main.js:286:7)
at StreamDispatcher.emit (events.js:200:13)
at StreamDispatcher.destroy (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\dispatcher\StreamDispatcher.js:294:10)
at AudioPlayer.destroyCurrentStream (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\AudioPlayer.js:77:18)
at VoiceConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\AudioPlayer.js:42:53)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
at VoiceConnection.emit (events.js:205:15)
at VoiceConnection.disconnect (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:311:10)
at VoiceChannel.leave (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\VoiceChannel.js:142:69)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\###\Desktop\real_bot_code\main.js:179:31)
```

Sorry if this is a bad example, im pretty new to stack and discord.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** In your `play()` function, you're referring to `message`, but it isn't defined within its [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).
**Solution:** Pass `message` as a parameter, for instance...

```js
function play(message, song) {
  const guild = message.guild;

  // rest of function code
}
```

...and then in your client's `message` event, call the function like so...

```js
play(message, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
```